# Copy SQL Server database for development but smaller

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

We have production database above 100Gig. I want to duplicate this database and give it to every developer to test its code, but the size is too large. Is there anyway I can backup just top 1000 rows with FK's and restore it to new DB? Or duplicate the DB first and delete all records from all tables, but keep 1000 rows with FK's or any other way to keep size below 5Gig.

I did search, but none of solutions were for tables having foreign keys.

Thanks,
Basheer

Comment: do you have a non-production server that you can copy over the production database and then reduce the size prior to the development?

Comment: Often transactional tables are very large and lookup tables are small. So you can simplify your replica by just copying _all_ lookup tables (that are referred to by the transactions), then whatever subset of transactions that you choose are always valid. This is a good middle ground for decreasing size without complexity. Otherwise you need to write a custom script that negotiates it's way through all FK's. If you have very large lookup tables then this mightn't be the one for you.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Yes I do have non-production server to run a copy of prod DB.

Answer (score 1):

This the IDEA:

**First:**

```
Create new database:
```

**Second:**
Select small records only like:

```
select top 500 from allYourTables
then insert to each every table to your new Database Created.
```

**Third:**

```
Dump the new database and give to its every developer
```

Hope it helps:

Assuming that you have a new `db_to_dev` Database name and you are working to your current database:
This  procedure will insert all the data from your working database, making sure that you had already a database created. `db_to_dev`:

Using `Information_Schema` you can select all your tables:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_TRANSFER_DATA @NUM_OF_RECORDS nvarchar(255)  as
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
DECLARE @message varchar(80), @tablename nvarchar(50);  
Declare @sqlstmt nvarchar(255);
PRINT '-------- List of tables --------';  
    DECLARE Schema_cursor CURSOR FOR   
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 

    OPEN Schema_cursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM Schema_cursor INTO @tablename 

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0   
        PRINT '         <<None>>'       
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        SELECT @message = '         ' + @tablename  
        set @sqlstmt =   'select top ' + @NUM_OF_RECORDS + ' * into [db_to_dev].[dbo].['+ @tablename +'] from ' + @tablename;
        EXEC  sp_executesql  @sqlstmt
        PRINT @message  
        FETCH NEXT FROM Schema_cursor INTO @tablename  
        END  

    CLOSE Schema_cursor  
    DEALLOCATE Schema_cursor  

END
```

To use:

With an option parameter:

```
EXEC PROC_TRANSFER_DATA '500'
```

Parameter value is depend on you if how many records you want to transfer into your new database `db_to_dev`.

This Stored Proc is tested.

Good luck

Comment: Good Idea. Set this up to run every half an our or so on your production SQL Server. At the end of each run, put the database backup (or MDF) somewhere where your developers can get it.

Comment: Thanks reds. Do I have to run this for every table? Can I do it all at once?

Comment: Updated the answer above to do it at once.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of projects on github which seek to do exactly that: make a subset that preserves referential integrity. Here is one such project:

https://github.com/18F/rdbms-subsetter